# SQL Query Works in DB Interface (Sequel Ace) but not on PHP Page

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

The following query runs and returns expected results in Sequel Ace, connecting to a MariaDB database, but returns NULL when run from PHP page. The connection and data are good, other queries on the same page return expected results.

The query:

```
SELECT Teacher, Period, AssessPeriod,
        ROUND(SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS Avg_Student_Growth_MOY,
        ROUND(SUM(`Annual Typical Growth Measure`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS Avg_Typical_Growth_Measure,
        ROUND((SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / SUM(`Annual Typical Growth Measure`)) * 100, 2) AS Percent_of_Typical_Growth,
        ROUND(SUM(`Annual Stretch Growth Measure`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS Avg_Stretch_Growth_Measure,
        ROUND((SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / SUM(`Annual Stretch Growth Measure`)) * 100, 2) AS Percent_of_Stretch_Growth
    FROM `iReadyResultsMath`
    JOIN `AllRosters2324Spring` ON `iReadyMSID` = `Student-ID`
    WHERE `Teacher` = 'TeacherName' AND `Period` = '0' AND `AssessPeriod` = 'MOY'
```

The Results:

| Teacher | Period | AssessPeriod | Avg_Student_Growth_MOY | Avg_Typical_Growth_Measure | Percent_of_Typical_Growth | Avg_Stretch_Growth_Measure | Percent_of_Stretch_Growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeacherName | 0 | MOY | 11.61 | 27.52 | 42.18 | 42.74 | 27.16 |

The PHP:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT
        ROUND(SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS `Avg_Student_Growth_MOY`,
        ROUND(SUM(`Annual Typical Growth Measure`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS `Avg_Typical_Growth_Measure`,
        ROUND((SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / SUM(`Annual Typical Growth Measure`)) * 100, 2) AS Percent_of_Typical_Growth,
        ROUND(SUM(`Annual Stretch Growth Measure`) / COUNT(*), 2) AS `Avg_Stretch_Growth_Measure`,
        ROUND((SUM(`Diagnostic Gain`) / SUM(`Annual Stretch Growth Measure`)) * 100, 2) AS `Percent_of_Stretch_Growth`
    FROM `iReadyResultsMath`
    JOIN `AllRosters2324Spring` ON `iReadyMSID` = `Student-ID`
    WHERE `Teacher` = '$teach' AND `Period` = '$per' AND `AssessPeriod` = 'MOY' ");
   
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    { 

    
    
    $asgm = $row["Avg_Student_Growth_MOY"];
    $atgm = $row['Avg_Typical_Growth_Measure'];
    $ptg = $row['Percent_of_Typical_Growth'];

}

var_dump($result);
?>
```

var_dump returns:

array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["Avg_Student_Growth_MOY"]=> NULL ["Avg_Typical_Growth_Measure"]=> NULL ["Percent_of_Typical_Growth"]=> NULL ["Avg_Stretch_Growth_Measure"]=> NULL ["Percent_of_Stretch_Growth"]=> NULL } }

Wrote up a query and tested in Sequel Ace expected the results to be the same when called in PHP script.

Comment: Are you sure that `$teach` and `$per` are what you expect them to be? (You know you've got potential SQL injection issues there?) What is `$chal`?

Comment: Yes $teach and $per are as expected, they are used on other queries on the page. $chal was a temporary variable I used to try and work out the problem, changed it back for the post. Thank you.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: After you do `$stmt->fetchAll()`, you can't use `$stmt->fetch()`. `fetchAll()` fetched everything, there's nothing left to fetch.

Comment: Just use `foreach ($result as $row)` to loop over the results.

Comment: If the query only returns one row, there's no need to use `fetchAll()` in the first place. Just call `fetch()` to get the row.